# How to make ntpd timeout when an Internet connection is not available

Tags: linux, redhat, ntpd

I am using the following command to synchronise the time on a Oracle Linux 6.5:

```
ntpd -gq
```

Unfortunately it does not timeout when an Internet connection is not available. Is this possible or should implement my own timeout mechanism?

Answer (score 5):

If you're on an intermittently connected machine like a laptop, consider using something other than ntpd, such as chrony, which is designed for situations like this. It is available in EPEL for RHEL 6 and is the default NTP client/server in RHEL 7.

To accomplish this, [set the `offline` option on the `server`s](http://chrony.tuxfamily.org/manual.html#server-directive) in your `chrony.conf` file, and then run the [`chronyc online` command](http://chrony.tuxfamily.org/manual.html#online-command) whenever you connect to the Internet.

Comment: +1: Didn't know about chrony!

Answer (score 0):

use ntpdate, such as:

```
ntpdate -t 10 cn.pool.ntp.org
```